# Sony A6000 remote control app

Tags: iphone, sony-alpha

Are there any apps for iPhone to remotely control the sony A6000 shutter click? 
(I am aware that it used to exist as Sony Play Memories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that it used to exist as Sony Play Memories.
It's now been re-branded it seems as "Imaging Edge Mobile".